# I am trying to assign a JAX Tracer object to a NumPy array that requires concrete values - work around needed please

Tags: jax, flax

I am new to Jax.

I am implementing a variational autoencoder (VAE) using Jax and Flax. During training, I sample a latent code (from the distribution inferred by the encoder, which I implement using compositions of flax.linen.nn modules). Crucially, in addition to passing this code through the decoder (as is standard for a VAE), I also pass the code to an external function (the MuJoCo physics engine), which tries to assign it to a NumPy array. This unsurprisingly leads to the following error:

TracerArrayConversionError: The numpy.ndarray conversion method **array**() was called on the JAX Tracer object...

Fundamentally, I need to pass a concrete numpy array to MuJoCo. **How can I make my variable a NumPy array will still allowing my model to be implemented in a computationally efficient manner using abstract tracers wherever possible?**

Here is a minimal working example of the problem I am facing - gym and mujoco (https://mujoco.org/) will need to be installed to run this I believe:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as np
import numpy as onp
import gym
from jax import jit

# create an instance of an open AI gym environment
env = gym.make('Humanoid-v3')
env.reset()

def this_fails(env, x):
    
    # this gives a TracerArrayConversionError
    env.sim.data.qpos[:] = x

    return env, x

x = np.arange(len(env.sim.data.qpos))
jit_this_fails = jax.jit(this_fails, static_argnums = 0)
env, x = jit_this_fails(env, x)
```

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: there is now a JAX FAQ entry on this topic: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-convert-a-jax-tracer-to-a-numpy-array*

---

*Note: this is the answer to the OP's question as originally written. The question has been edited multiple times and no longer asks what it originally asked.*

In the past this sort of thing has not been supported, but you can do this with the new `jax.pure_callback` feature that is part of JAX version 0.3.17, which is not yet released at the time I am writing this.

For example, say you want to call a numpy-based function from within a JAX jit-compiled function; we'll use `np.sin` for simplicity. You might first try something like this:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

@jax.jit
def this_fails(x):
  # Call a numpy function...
  return np.sin(x)

x = jnp.arange(5.0)
this_fails(x)
```

```
jax._src.errors.TracerArrayConversionError: The numpy.ndarray conversion method __array__() was called on the JAX Tracer object Traced<ShapedArray(float32[5])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=0/1)>
The error occurred while tracing the function this_fails at tmp.py:7 for jit. This concrete value was not available in Python because it depends on the value of the argument 'x'.
See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError
```

The result is a `TracerConversionError`, because you're attempting to pass a traced JAX value into a function that expects a numpy array (side note: see  [How To Think In JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/thinking_in_jax.html) for an introduction to JAX Tracers and related topics).

In JAX version 0.3.17 or newer, you can get around this issue using `jax.pure_callback`:

```py
@jax.jit
def numpy_callback(x):
  # Need to forward-declare the shape & dtype of the expected output.
  result_shape = jax.core.ShapedArray(x.shape, x.dtype)
  return jax.pure_callback(np.sin, result_shape, x)

x = jnp.arange(5.0)
print(numpy_callback(x))
```

```
[ 0.         0.841471   0.9092974  0.14112   -0.7568025]
```

A few caveats to keep in mind:

- the resulting execution will rely on a callback to the host, so it will be quite slow on accelerators like GPU/TPU, particularly in distributed/multi-host settings. In the case of local CPU execution, though, it avoids buffer copies and can be quite performant.
- if you `vmap` the function, it will result in a `for` loop of multiple callbacks (you can specify `vectorized=True` if the callback function handles batches natively).
- autodiff transformations like `grad` and `jacobian` will not work with this function, because JAX has no way of reasoning about the computations being done. If you would like to use it with autodiff transformations, you could define custom gradients as in [Custom Derivative Rules](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Custom_derivative_rules_for_Python_code.html), though this would require having access to a function that computes the gradient for your callback function.

None of this is documented yet on the JAX website, but we hope to write docs for `pure_callback` soon!

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed response. Can I ask 1) when will JAX version 0.3.17 be released, and 2) is it possible to use the pure_callback function prior to this release (e.g. is their pre-release code that I can use to create my own function)?

Comment: I'm not sure when 0.3.17 will be released, but you can install from source now using e.g. `pip install git+https://github.com/google/jax.git`. Alternatively, you can use older existing APIs to do a similar thing; there is an example here: https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/11680

Comment: I just installed 0.3.17. Thank you! However, pure_callback seems to be for calling a Python function, whereas I am trying to assign the Jax Tracer Object values to a NumPy array for use outside of Jax (I need access to the concrete values). In the pure_callback documentation here (jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/jax/_src/api.html) it says that pure_callback returns a NumPy array. However, for me, it returns a Jax Tracer Object, so it doesn't help me, unless I am missing something?

Comment: pure_callback is for passing a traced value to a numpy function which requires a concrete numpy array as input, so I think it's precisely what you need. i.e. the way to convert a traced value to a numpy array is to pass it to a function via pure_callback. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your response again jakevdp. I'm still struggling to see how I can use pure_callback to achieve my goal. I have now edited my original post to add a MWE , which also includes a few commented out attempts to use pure_callback. Would you mind taking a look for me please?

Comment: The issue in your MWE is different than your original question: you're attempting to update a global variable within the jit-compiled function; this kind of side-effect is not supported in JAX (see [JAX: Pure Functions](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#pure-functions)) Instead you'll need to explicitly pass any objects you want to modify as inputs and outputs to your function.

Comment: Hi jakevdp. The global nature of env is not important as in the full version of my code I pass env around my functions. Apologies for confusing you there by oversimplifying my MWE (hopefully I haven't oversimplified it in other respects too). I have updated the MWE to reflect this. Given this clarification, can you provide further help? To reiterate, I really appreciate your help here, as I really don't know how to make progress and this problem relates to a central component of the model I am creating.

Comment: In your updated version, you're still relying on side-effects (the function modifies the input `env` but does not return it). If you want to JIT-compile a function that modifies its inputs, you should return the modified variable (i.e.. `return env`) and capture the output when calling the function. For more details see the *Pure Function* docs I linked to above.

Comment: I still experience the TracerArrayConversionError after returning env and capturing the output (see updated MWE). In addition, when I return env, I now get an additional TypeError error when I attempt to use pure_feedback in this setting (see 'pure_callback attempt 2' in MWE)

Comment: I have no idea what's going on in your question anymore with all the edits and comments, I don't think this medium is working.

Comment: Hi jake. I added in the comments so that you could see how I was attempting to use pure_callback; I thought this would be helpful but apparently it has added confusion so I have removed those comments. It should be pretty clear what the question is now.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not familiar with the `gym` package or what kind of object `env` is, and I was unable to run your code even after installing `gym`,  `glfw`, `myjoco`, and a few other packages that reported as import errors the first time through. But from the behavior you report, it sounds like `env` is not built to be compatible with JAX functions. I'd suggest inquiring with the gym help forums on whether it can be used together with JAX, or perhaps asking a new stack overflow question that highlights gym rather than repeatedly editing this one.

Comment: I shall do that. Thank you for all your help and assistance. My sincere apologies for not wording my question correctly from the start.